# C++: Filling vector from the pipe

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to fill my `vector<float>` from command line:

```
more my.txt | myexe.x > result.txt
```

What is the best way to open the pipe in C++?
Thanks
Arman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your shell will connect the standard output of `more` to the standard input of `myexe.x`. So you can just read from `std::cin`, and need not worry whether the input comes from the keyboard or from some other program.

For example:

```
vector<float> myVec;
copy(istream_iterator<float>(cin), istream_iterator<float>(),
     back_inserter(myVec));
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, but what about end of the inputs? should I check in the end EOF? or what?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `std::copy()` from `<algorithm>`, but you don't need that extra dependency.

```
#include<iterator>

// ...
std::vector<float> them_numbers(std::istream_iterator<float>(std::cin),
                                std::istream_iterator<float>());
```

If you know beforehand exactly how many values you expect, then you can avoid the reallocations:

```
std::vector<float>::size_type all_of_them /* = ... */;
std::vector<float> them_numbers(all_of_them);
them_numbers.assign(std::istream_iterator<float>(std::cin),
                    std::istream_iterator<float>());
```

Answer (score 2):

That particular pipe is attached to your app's stdin, so you can just read from there.